# Is a sigma-finite Borel measure over $\mathbb R$ determined by its values on the continuous functions?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, borel-sets

Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are sigma-finite measures on the Borel sigma-algebra over $\mathbb R$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R}f\,d\mu=\int_{\mathbb R}f\,d\nu$ for all nonnegative continuous functions $f$ on $\mathbb R$. Does it always follow that $\mu=\nu$? Some related information can be found at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155776/to-define-a-measure-is-it-sufficient-to-define-how-to-integrate-continuous-func)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be counting measure on the rationals and $\nu$ the translate of $\mu$ by an irrational.  Then for nonnegative continuous functions $f$ on $\mathbb R$,
$$ \int f \; d\mu = \int f \; d\nu = \cases{0 & if $f \equiv 0$\cr
 +\infty & otherwise\cr}$$

Comment: But $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Looks $\sigma$-finite to me.

Comment: Oops, I wasn't making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have deleted this response since it referred to a previous answer whose deletion has rendered it incomprehensible.